# Ajax second request fails

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to update some div block next way ->
my view for update :

```
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Show",
             "About",
             new AjaxOptions
             {
                 HttpMethod = "POST",
                 InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                 UpdateTargetId = "updateMe"
             })
     <div id="updateMe"> </div>
```

my controller:

```
    int count  = 0;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult About()
    {

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {   
            count++;
            ViewBag.count  = count;
            return PartialView();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

my PartialView:

```
    <h1>Hellow from Partial View !  @ViewBag.count </h1>
```

Also I have this in .config file

```
      <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

and referenced libriries:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Expected: first click:
 Hellow from Partial View ! 1

second:
 Hellow from Partial View ! 2

have:  Hellow from Partial View ! 1

?

Comment: The controller is created every request, you don't carry the value over to the next request.

Comment: you are right! I make field static and all works! thanks!

Comment: I added an answer with some extra information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Controller` class is initialised every request again and therefore the value of your field `count` is being reinitialised every time. You would want to have this "globally". One way is to define it as a `static` field; but be warned, this may have some unexpected behaviour (like [static field in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5661202/static-field-in-asp-net-mvc)).